# How to create pst file without Microsoft Outlook installed?

Tags: .net, vb.net, outlook

Lets say I dont have Microsoft Outlook in my computer.

How to create C:\Backup.pst file without Microsoft Outlook installed?

I am looking for vb.net code for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **You can't**. You have to get the MAPI namespace and to do that you need an instance of Outlook...

Comment: Please do not just throw every tag at a question to get more views. Use ONLY relevant tags, otherwise you're abusing the system and helping to make tags useless.  I've removed those that don't apply.

Comment: Your only option would be to understand the binary format of a PST file and build it byte by byte. There is a .NET implementation of Open XML for DOCX, XLSX and the like but PST files do not use Open XML so that's no help. Without Outlook Interop you would need to either know the binary format or use some third-party library that knows it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can

1. Build the PST file yourself, its format is documented https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff385210%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396.
2. Use an existing component, such as PST.Net (http://www.independentsoft.com/pst/index.html). I have not used it, so I don't know how good it is.
3. Use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) to create a temporary profile to add a new PST to it. You would still need to have the MAPI system installed, which means either Outlook or the standalone version of MAPI (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39045) must be installed. Note that the latter does not support Unicode PST file.
4. Use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language - I am its author) - it still requires Outlook or the standalone version of MAPI to have a functioning MAPI system, but it allows to create PST files without running Outlook.

```
    set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
    set Store = Session.LogonPstStore("c:\temp\test.pst")
    Store.ValidateIPMTree 
    set Inbox = Store.GetDefaultFolders(olFolderInbox)
    set Items = Inbox.Items
    set Msg = Items.Add
    Msg.Sent = true
    Msg.Subject = "test"
    Msg.Body = "test message"
    Msg.Save
    set Msg = Nothing
    set Items = Nothing
    set Inbox = Nothing
    set Store = Nothing
    Session.Logoff
```